# How to calculate geodesic vector field of exist time function?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, geodesic

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact non-trapping manifold with strictly convex boundary. We have to show that
$$
X \tilde{\tau}=-2
$$
where $\tilde{\tau}=\tau(x, v)-\tau(x,-v) .$ If $(x, v) \in S M$, let $\tau(x, v) \in[0, \infty]$ be the first time when $\gamma_{x, v}(t)$ exits $\boldsymbol{M}$
$$
\tau(x, v):=\sup \left\{t \geq 0 ; \gamma_{x, v}([0, t]) \subset M\right\}
$$
We call $(M, g)$ non-trapping, if $\tau(x, v)<\infty$ for each $(x, v) \in S M$.
Define geodesic flow on $S N$ as
$$
\varphi_{t}: S N \rightarrow S N, \quad \varphi_{t}(x, v)=\left(\gamma_{x, v}(t), \dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(t)\right)
$$
The geodesic vector field $X: C^{\infty}(S N) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(S N)$, which differentiates a function on $S N$ along geodesic flow:
$$
X w(x, v)=\left.\frac{d}{d s} w\left(\varphi_{s}(x, v)\right)\right|_{s=0}
$$

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
     X \tilde{\tau}(x,v)&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\tilde {\tau}(\varphi_t(x,v))\right|_{t=0}\\
     &=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(\tau(\varphi_t(x,v))-\tau(\varphi_t(x,-v)) \right) \right|_{t=0}
 \end{align*}
I know that $\tau(\varphi_t(x,v))=\tau(x,v)-t$. And also $\tau(\varphi_t(x,-v)=\tau(x,-v)-t$. So this implies

\begin{align*}
     X \tilde{\tau}(x,v)&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\tilde {\tau}(\varphi_t(x,v))\right|_{t=0}\\
     &=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(\tau(\varphi_t(x,v))-\tau(\varphi_t(x,-v)) \right)
\right|_{t=0}\\
&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(\tau(x,v)-t-(\tau(x,-v)-t) \right) \right|_{t=0}\\
     &=0.
 \end{align*}

Where I am missing I do not know. Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:
\begin{align}
\varphi_t(x,-v) &= \left(\gamma_{x,-v}(t), \gamma'_{x,-v}(t) \right) \\
&= \left( \gamma_{x,v}(-t),-\gamma'_{x,v}(-t)\right).
\end{align}
Therefore:
$$
\tau(\varphi_t(x,v)) = \tau (x,v)-t
$$
and
$$
\tau(\varphi_{-t}(x,v)) = \tau(\gamma_{x,v}(-t),-\gamma'_{x,v}(-t)) = \tau(x,-v) + t.
$$
It follows that $\overline\tau(\varphi_t(x,v)) = -2t + \tau(x,v) - \tau(x,-v)$ and the result follows from a direct computation.